# HTTP Status 500 file not found error in jsp include

Tags: jsp, filenotfoundexception, http-status-code-500, jspinclude

I include file from my root directory. Its working fine in local but when I host my site its give me:

> error HTTP Status 500: "../connection.jsp" not found

My files are in

> public_html/myfolder/connection.jsp

on shared hosting.

I want to include file in

> public_html/myfolder/process/user-login.jsp

Comment: Can you please paste the server logs?

Comment: I think you should set permission to  `chmod` `7777` of your file which is including required file. so that it can access with full permissions.

Comment: @LukyBoy-KU You are obviously not concerned about security.

Comment: @LukyBoy-KU i already change permission chmod 7777 but its not working

Comment: yes we should not practice `chmod` `7777` due to security reason. but for testing purpose we can do so temporarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `public_html` is a root folder of your web application, then you can use absolute path to the included resource.

```jsp
<jsp:include page="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/myfolder/connection.jsp"/>
```

Comment: i have file in public_html/myFolder/.

Comment: i have file in public_html/MyFolder/connection.jsp and i want to include file in public_html/MyFolder/process/user-registration.jsp.

Comment: make sure you spell `Myfolder` correctly because it's case sensitive.

Comment: sorry typing mistake. but the name in website is same.

Comment: is this answer helped you?